# How do I change operating systems. From OSMC to NOOBS on Raspberry Pi 2. Both OS are on one sandisk

Tags: boot

I have a Raspberry Pi 2.  With 2 OS on one sandisk.  I need a way to choose between them.

Answer (score 2):

When you boot your Pi you should be presented with a boot menu where you can select which OS you want to use.

If you don’t select an OS, then the last booted OS will be used after a short delay.